# Custom UIButton Frame not drawing correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-core

I'm building my own custom button through its layer like so:

```
[self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.94 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.layer setBorderWidth:1];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.86 alpha:1]];
[self.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AdelleBasic-Bold" size:18]];
[self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];

[self.layer setShadowRadius:4];
[self.layer setShadowOpacity:.4];
[self.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.5 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.layer setCornerRadius:5];
```

The result is this: [image]

It appears the the font is higher than it should be, but if you look closely, it's actually the button's frame that is being drawn too low: the font and drop shadow are where they're suppose to be.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Does this happen when you remove `[self setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it at all different alignments.

Comment: But I mean do you have this rendering issue when you remove this line of code?

Comment: Yes, originally that line wasn't there at all, it was added as an attempt to correct the problem